# ZeroMQ reliability on bad links

Tags: zeromq

I am wondering how ZeroMQ behaves if messages are delivered over a bad quality link, e.g. a very unstable, low level serial connection which might drop **individual bytes**.

Of course in such a case the affected message will be lost, but will ZeroMQ be able to recover with the next message? Does it find the start again in any case?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The connection reliability is mostly the responsibility of the TCP protocol - if a socket believes it's connected, then the message is getting through.  If packets are lost, then TCP detects that and attempts to retransmit them ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Data_transfer) for more info).  This all happens "for free" as far as ZMQ is concerned, any connection type using TCP will behave the same way.

When the TCP connection is lost, which, presumably, could occur if the connection is *very* unreliable and the message never gets through after repeated attempts by TCP, then ZMQ adds *another*, separate layer of reliability on top of that, allowing your application to reconnect.

What happens with the original or subsequent messages during this outage depends on the ZMQ socket type you've chosen.  Some socket types drop messages, some socket types queue them.  If the message was already in transit, it may be lost because the sending socket has relinquished control over it.

Generally, if you want absolute reliability in message delivery, you'll be writing that yourself in your application, with your own confirmations that messages have been received.  In most cases, something less than total reliability is needed and you'll just rely on TCP and ZMQ to get the job mostly done.  If you're so focused on performance that even the reliability of TCP will slow you down too much and you'd rather just discard that data and move on, you'll need to use UDP - I've heard of people using UDP with ZMQ, but I haven't tried it and I don't believe it's fully supported across the board.